# OpenLayers 2: draw path with only two points

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I want to draw a path with no more then 2 points. On the second point I want the path to be finished.

can anyone help me how to get this functionality achieved in openlayers 2.

I tried this code but it gives error although lines are created well.

```
        _singleLineControl = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(
            _singleLineLayer,
            OpenLayers.Handler.Path,
            {
                eventListeners: { "featureadded": drawingFinished },
                callbacks: {
                    point: function (pointGeometry, lineGeometry) {
                        var numPoints = lineGeometry.getVertices().length;
                        if (numPoints == 3) {
                            this.drawFeature(lineGeometry);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        viewer.addControl(_singleLineControl);
        _singleLineControl.handler.single = true;
        _singleLineControl.handler.freehand = false;
        _singleLineControl.deactivate();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found solution myself :) using `maxVertices`

```
        // single line drawing control
        _singleLineControl = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(
            _singleLineLayer,
            OpenLayers.Handler.Path,
            {
                eventListeners: { "featureadded": drawingFinished },
                handlerOptions: {
                    maxVertices: 2,
                    single: true,
                    freehand: false,
                }
            });
        viewer.addControl(_singleLineControl); 
        _singleLineControl.deactivate();
```